# curl ssh key C++ error "Username/PublicKey combination invalid"

Tags: c++, curl, ssh

I'm working on embedded system in C++.
I'm actualy try to connect my system on ssh to my computer host.
I use this code:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) {

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
                 "sftp://10.0.0.100/");
  /* Define our callback to get called when there's data to be written */

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:password");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD,"password");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 22);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1000);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 10);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
  /* Set a pointer to our struct to pass to the callback */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ftpfile);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE,std::string(PublicKey).c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE,std::string(PrivateKey).c_str());

  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES,CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY);

  /* Switch on full protocol/debug output */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

  /* always cleanup */
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

but the result of my programme is:

- Trying 10.0.0.100...
- Connected to 10.0.0.100 (10.0.0.100) port 22 (#0)
- SSH MD5 fingerprint: dfdaa04ed1f80caf1e588349846b7025
- SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
- Using SSH public key file '/opt/appl/var/PublicKey'
- Using SSH private key file '/opt/appl/var/PrivateKey'
- SSH public key authentication failed: Username/PublicKey combination invalid
- Authentication failure
- Closing connection 0

Unfortunately i can't creat some `ssh` key on my system because it dosen't accept `system()` commandes so i directly import keys from another system.

Dose it the cause of my error?

Comment: I think the problem occurs when you configure CURL for two different ssl authentication method (user/password and public key), and both using at the same time are not compatible. So, you should  erase user and password configuration (or public key) in your code and think if the public/private key uses a key password  you need add curl_easy_setopt(hCurl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, "password"). I hope it helps you

Comment: I remove curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:password"); line but that's doesn't solved the problem :(
I always get the same result.

Comment: Searching for the web I found [this](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-07/0102.html). You need to add curl_easy_setopt(curlUp, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "user"). And maybe your key pair is not compatible, be sure about that.

Comment: always the same error

Comment: I'm afraid about my key pair is not compatible. If i import the key pair, dose that can work or the key pair must be generated on the same system?

Comment: About host, dose i must specifie any client for enable connection?

Comment: The key generation may be in any system, only be sure to use openssh. About client I am not sure. try to follow the code in the link before.

Comment: Yea, but unfortunatly on my system, i havn't the rights to access at this repertory & files.
That's why i try to import keys.
& I havn't ssh-agent enable & i can't enable thems

Comment: You can import any keys but make sure, this keys was created using openssh and not Putty (for example).

Comment: Yea it was openssl:       
file PublicKey     
PublicKey: OpenSSH RSA public key          

file PrivateKey      
PrivateKey: PEM RSA private key

Comment: & About my usename: i set it with my $USER session on my system?

Comment: I think it better use the function getenv("USER"), instead $USER....

Comment: Yea but i can't use system fonctions.  and in my code, getenv("USER") return null in my stsem. i not directly use $USER variable. if i type echo $USER in my shell commande that's return the variable that's i integer in my code